# How to programmatically set Layout to Top and Start of screen?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

You can set a `LinearLayout` to the top left of a screen by doing this:

```
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

I was wondering how would I do this programmatically?

I have the following piece of code:

```
 LinearLayout btnBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnBar);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnBarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight / 3);
 //Not sure how to set the layout to the top left.
```

but in LayoutParameters there is no `addRule()` method so I am not sure how to set these attributes. The `LinearLayout` is inside a `RelativeLayout`.

EDIT: I think I figured it out, but I am getting a exception. Here is my solution:

```
   LinearLayout btnBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnBar);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnBarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight / 3);
    btnBarParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
    btnBar.setLayoutParams(btnBarParams);
```

But I cannot see if this is working because I get a exception on the last line of my solution saying

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: Looks like `btnBar` is a `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

```
 LinearLayout btnBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnBar);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnBarParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight / 3);
    btnBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    btnBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    btnBar.setLayoutParams(btnBarParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it will work,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

btnBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```